# Modernize Jquery shadows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

Hello i have found a great website and i want to use that effect, here is the link http://dotmick.com/

I need help with those lines that following mouse and stop on element, can some one help me with that, i dont know where to look that, is there some similar jquery animation, i think i have found it here, 
http://dotmick.com/cms/site/themes/dotfolio/js/script.js

But still to complicated, little point to similar example will be nice

Txanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you ask him if you can use it first (mick.larch@gmail.com). Copying a person's code without permission is illegal.

Comment: I have asked him, i was thinking this is can do with simple free jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an simple jquery animation. Unfortunately, there's no "easy" answer with this one. Thankfully, they didn't obfuscate their code. Below is the pretty-printed version of it:

```
var spinner;
var fx = true;
var canvas;
var context;
var RADIUS = 205;
var RADIUS_SCALE = 1;
var RADIUS_SCALE_MIN = 1;
var RADIUS_SCALE_MAX = 1;
var QUANTITY = 40;
var particles;
var mouseX = 50;
var mouseY = 50;
var timeout = 0;
var looping = 0;
var erasingTotal = 3000;
var erasingCounter = 0;
var stopped = true;
var overThumb = false;
var prevMouseX, prevMouseY;
var prevScroll = 0;
var page = "home";
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.browser, {SafariMobile: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iP(hone|ad|od)/i)});
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.browser, {iPhone: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iPhone/i)});
    if ($.browser.SafariMobile) {
        toggleFx()
    }
    if ($.browser.SafariMobile) {
        $("html").attr("class", "iphone")
    }
    $("div#preloader").css("height", $(document).height());
    $.fn.spin = function(d) {
        this.each(function() {
            var e = $(this), f = e.data("spinner");
            if (f) {
                f.stop()
            }
            if (d !== false) {
                d = $.extend({color: e.css("color")}, d);
                f = new Spinner(d).spin(this);
                e.data("spinner", f)
            }
        });
        return this
    };
    var b = {lines: 10,length: 0,width: 20,radius: 0,color: "#353535",speed: 1.6,trail: 63,shadow: false};
    var c = document.getElementById("preloader");
    spinner = new Spinner(b).spin(c);
    $(spinner.el).css("left", window.innerWidth * 0.5);
    $(spinner.el).css("top", (window.innerHeight - $(window).scrollTop()) * 0.5);
    window.addEventListener("resize", a, false);
    function a() {
        if ($("div#preloader").css("display") != "none") {
            $(spinner.el).css("left", window.innerWidth * 0.5);
            $(spinner.el).css("top", (window.innerHeight - $(window).scrollTop()) * 0.5);
            return
        }
    }
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("pointer-events", "none");
    $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("cursor", "default");
    $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".projectThumbnail").each(function() {
        var n = $(this);
        n.css({position: "absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass("img_grayscale").css({position: "absolute","z-index": "998",opacity: "0"}).insertBefore(n).queue(function() {
            var o = $(this);
            o.parent().css({width: this.width,height: this.height});
            o.dequeue()
        });
        this.src = d(this.src)
    });
    $(".projectPreview").click(f);
    function l() {
        overThumb = false;
        $("#upLink").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $("#upLink").css("display", "none")
        });
        $("section#screens ul").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $("section#works").css("height", "auto");
            $("section#screens ul li").each(function() {
                $(this).css("display", "none")
            })
        });
        $("section#works ul").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $("#backLink").css("display", "none");
            $(".projectPreview").each(function() {
                $(this).css("display", "block")
            });
            $(window).scrollTop(prevScroll);
            $("section#works").css("width", "75%");
            page = "home";
            e();
            overThumb = true;
            mouseX = prevMouseX;
            mouseY = prevMouseY;
            $("section#works ul").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            })
        })
    }
    function f() {
        var p = $(this);
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        var n = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        prevMouseX = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() * 0.5;
        prevMouseY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height() * 0.5;
        prevScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        recordOutboundLink(this, "Projects", n);
        page = "project";
        $("section#works ul").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $(".projectPreview").each(function() {
                $(this).css("display", "none")
            });
            $("#backLink").css("display", "block");
            $("section#works").css("left", "30px");
            $("section#works").css("width", "250px");
            overThumb = true;
            mouseX = $("#backImg").offset().left + $("#backImg").width() * 0.5;
            mouseY = $("#backImg").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $("#backImg").height() * 0.5;
            $("section#works ul").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
                overThumb = false;
                $("section#screens ul li").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr("id") != "project_" + n) {
                        $(this).css("display", "none")
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("display", "block")
                    }
                });
                $("section#works").css("height", $("section#screens").height());
                if ($(document).height() > $(window).height() + 400) {
                    $("#upLink").css("display", "block");
                    $("#upLink").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint")
                }
                $("section#screens ul").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint")
            })
        })
    }
    function g() {
        overThumb = false;
        a();
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").css("pointer-events", "none");
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").css("cursor", "default");
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 500, "easeOutQuint");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("pointer-events", "auto");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("cursor", "auto");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint");
        if (page == "project") {
            $("section#screens ul").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
                $("section#screens ul").css("display", "none")
            });
            if ($("#upLink").css("display") == "block") {
                $("#upLink").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
                    $("#upLink").css("display", "none")
                })
            }
        }
        $("section#works").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $("section#works").css("display", "none");
            $("section#about").css("display", "block");
            $("section#about").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint")
        })
    }
    function b() {
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").css("pointer-events", "auto");
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").css("cursor", "auto");
        $("nav#nav #nav_about").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("pointer-events", "none");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").css("cursor", "default");
        $("nav#nav #nav_projects").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 500, "easeOutQuint");
        $("section#about").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
            $("section#about").css("display", "none");
            $("section#works").css("display", "block");
            $("section#works").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint", function() {
                if (page == "project") {
                    $("section#screens ul").css("display", "block");
                    $("section#screens ul").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint");
                    if ($("#upLink").css("display") == "none" && $(document).height() > $(window).height() + 400) {
                        $("#upLink").css("display", "block");
                        $("#upLink").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "easeOutQuint")
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        overThumb = false;
        a()
    });
    $(".projectThumbnail").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("img:first").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        overThumb = true;
        mouseX = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() * 0.5;
        mouseY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height() * 0.5
    });
    $(".projectThumbnail").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
        overThumb = false
    });
    $("#backImg").mouseover(function() {
        overThumb = true;
        mouseX = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() * 0.5;
        mouseY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height() * 0.5
    });
    $("#backImg").mouseout(function() {
        overThumb = false
    });
    $("#upImg").mouseover(function() {
        overThumb = true;
        mouseX = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() * 0.5;
        mouseY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height() * 0.5
    });
    $("#upImg").mouseout(function() {
        overThumb = false
    });
    $("#fxToggle").click(toggleFx);
    $("#backLink").click(l);
    $("#nav #nav_about a").attr("href", "#");
    $("#nav #nav_about a").click(g);
    $("#nav #nav_projects a").attr("href", "#");
    $("#nav #nav_projects a").click(b);
    function m() {
        if (jQuery.browser.mozilla && jQuery.browser.version.slice(0, 3) == "1.9") {
            $(".projectThumbnail").each(function(n) {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
                $(this).attr("src", "");
                $(this).attr("alt", "")
            })
        }
        $("html").css("display", "block");
        canvas = document.getElementById("bkgd");
        if (canvas != undefined) {
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            e()
        }
    }
    spinner.stop();
    m();
    $("div#preloader").animate({opacity: 0}, 2400, "linear", function() {
        $("div#preloader").css("display", "none");
        $("html").css("overflow-y", "auto");
        if (canvas != undefined) {
            window.addEventListener("resize", e, false);
            h();
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", c, false)
        }
    });
    function e() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        if (page == "project") {
            return
        }
        var p = window.innerWidth * 0.75;
        var o = Math.floor(p / 220);
        var n = (o == 1) ? 200 : (o - 1) * 220 + 200;
        $("section#works").css("left", (window.innerWidth - n) * 0.5)
    }
    function c(n) {
        if (!fx) {
            return
        }
        stopped = false;
        if (looping <= 0 && overThumb) {
            looping = setInterval(j, 40)
        }
        if (!overThumb) {
            stopped = true
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            stopped = true
        }, 3000)
    }
    function h() {
        particles = [];
        var n = 20;
        for (var o = 0; o < QUANTITY; o++) {
            var p = {position: {x: mouseX,y: mouseY},shift: {x: mouseX,y: mouseY},size: 0.2,angle: 0,speed: 0.01 + Math.random() * 1,targetSize: 0.2,fillColor: "rgba(" + n + ", " + n + ", " + n + ", 1.0)",orbit: RADIUS * 0.5};
            particles.push(p)
        }
    }
    function a() {
        stopped = true;
        var n = 0;
        clearInterval(looping);
        looping = 0;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(239,239,239,1.0)";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        n++
    }
    function j() {
        RADIUS_SCALE = Math.min(RADIUS_SCALE, RADIUS_SCALE_MAX);
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(235,235,235,0.17)";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        if (stopped == true) {
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
            context.fillStyle = "rgba(239,239,239,0.1)";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
            erasingCounter += 40;
            if (erasingCounter >= erasingTotal) {
                clearInterval(looping);
                looping = 0;
                erasingCounter = 0
            }
            return
        }
        for (i = 0, len = particles.length; i < len; i++) {
            var o = particles[i];
            var n = {x: o.position.x,y: o.position.y};
            o.angle += o.speed;
            o.shift.x += (mouseX - o.shift.x) * (o.speed);
            o.shift.y += (mouseY - o.shift.y) * (o.speed);
            o.position.x = o.shift.x + Math.cos(i + o.angle) * (o.orbit * RADIUS_SCALE);
            o.position.y = o.shift.y + Math.sin(i + o.angle) * (o.orbit * RADIUS_SCALE);
            o.position.x = Math.max(Math.min(o.position.x, canvas.width), 0);
            o.position.y = Math.max(Math.min(o.position.y, canvas.height), 0);
            o.size += (o.targetSize - o.size) * 0.05;
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = o.fillColor;
            context.strokeStyle = o.fillColor;
            context.lineWidth = o.size;
            context.moveTo((0.5 + n.x) | 0, (0.5 + n.y) | 0);
            context.lineTo((0.5 + o.position.x) | 0, (0.5 + o.position.y) | 0);
            context.stroke();
            context.arc((0.5 + o.position.x) | 0, (0.5 + o.position.y) | 0, o.size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.fill()
        }
    }
    function d(n) {
        var p = document.createElement("canvas");
        var v = p.getContext("2d");
        var q = new Image();
        q.src = n;
        p.width = q.width;
        p.height = q.height;
        v.drawImage(q, 0, 0);
        var o = v.getImageData(0, 0, p.width, p.height);
        o = k(o, 100, -50);
        for (var t = 0; t < o.height; t++) {
            for (var u = 0; u < o.width; u++) {
                var r = (t * 4) * o.width + u * 4;
                var s = (o.data[r] + o.data[r + 1] + o.data[r + 2]) / 3;
                o.data[r] = s;
                o.data[r + 1] = s;
                o.data[r + 2] = s
            }
        }
        v.putImageData(o, 0, 0, 0, 0, o.width, o.height);
        return p.toDataURL()
    }
    function k(s, n, p) {
        var r = s.data;
        for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o += 4) {
            r[o] = q(r[o], 0.2, 0.25);
            r[o + 1] = q(r[o], 0.2, 0.25);
            r[o + 2] = q(r[o], 0.2, 0.25)
        }
        function q(u, v, t) {
            u = u / 255;
            if (v < 0) {
                u = u * (1 + v)
            } else {
                u = u + ((1 - u) * v)
            }
            u = (u - 0.5) * (Math.tan((t + 1) * Math.PI / 4)) + 0.5;
            return u * 255
        }
        return s
    }
});
function toggleFx() {
    fx = !fx;
    $("#bkgd").css("display", (!fx) ? "none" : "block");
    $("#fxToggle a").text((fx) ? "fx enabled" : "fx disabled")
};
```

The key variable to look for here is `overThumb` which looks like it determines whether the animation should be shown or not. For instance:

```
$("#backImg").mouseout(function() {
    overThumb = false
});
$("#upImg").mouseover(function() {
    overThumb = true;
    mouseX = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() * 0.5;
    mouseY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height() * 0.5
});
$("#upImg").mouseout(function() {
    overThumb = false
});
```

You can see than, when the mouse is over a thumbnail, it sets it to `true`, otherwise it is `false`. There is a timer in this code that looks at this variable and decides how to animate the particles. I hope this helps!

Comment: Txanks mate, this was great, i will try something